# Get entire hierarchy of categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set up a hierarchal list of categories for my woocommerce site. This is hard to describe but what I have is something similar to this for product categories...

```
Animals
 -Dog
  --Beagle
  --Poodle
 -Cat
 -Rabbit
Cars
 -Chevy
 -Toyota
People
Cities
Planets
```

If I'm looking at the Poodle page I want to display this as my list of categories..

```
Animals
 -Dog
  --Beagle
  --Poodle
```

Here is the code I have currently..

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'child_of' => get_queried_object()->term_id,
    //'child_of' => 6,
    'title_li' => __( 'Categories' ),
    'depth' => 3
);

wp_list_categories( $args ); 
?>
```

I'm able to make this work if I set a specific term ID for `child_of` (commented out above). But I'd like for this to work automatically. Basically I need it to loop back through all of the categories and start listing terms from its highest level category.

Its almost like displaying a breadcrumb, but showing all children categories under the first level category.

Comment: plus one for using `get_queried_object()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two properties you should be interested in in the term object which you get back from `get_queried_object()` and that is

- `term_id` which is the ID of the term
- `parent` which is an integer value of the term's parent. This value is either `0` if the term is top level or any other integer value which is equal the term ID of the current term's parent

With this in mind, we can use `parent` to determine if the term being viewed is a top level term or a term lower down in the hierarchy. This only solves half the issue though as we still do not know when `parent` is not `0` if that term is a child or grandchild term. To determine that, we will use `get_ancestors()` to get all the hierarchy of the current term, and from there we can get the top level term

`get_ancestors()` return an array of term ids, the last id being the top level term and the first id beign the direct parent of the term passed. For top level terms, an empty array will be returned. As there are overheads here, we will first check if the current term is a top level term or not before we run `get_ancestors()`

For large blocks of code, it is always easier for me to write a proper wrapper function which I can call into my templates as needed, so lets code the function

```
/**
 * Function to display all terms from a given taxonomy in a hierarchy
 *
 * @param (array) $args Array of valid parameters for wp_list_categories
 */
function custom_term_list( $args = [] )
{
    // Make sure that this is a taxonomy term archive for the ttaxonomy 'product_cat', if not, return
    if ( !is_tax( 'product_cat' ) )
        return;

    // Get the current term object
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // Check if current term is top level or not
    if ( 0 == $term->parent ) {
        // Show all terms in hierarchy below the current term
        $parent = $term->term_id; 
        // If you need to show all terms regardless, you can do the following
        //$parent = 0;
    } else { // Term is not top level
        $hierarchy = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy );
        $parent    = end( $hierarchy );
    }

    // Make sure we override `child_of` if it is set by the user
    $args['child_of'] = $parent;
    // Make sure we set the taxonomy to the term object's taxonomy property
    $args['taxonomy'] = $term->taxonomy;

    wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

Before we look at how to use the function, a few notes:

- The code is untested and might be buggy. be sure to testthis locally first with debug set to true
- The code requires at least PHP 5.4
- I have written the code to only work on taxonomy archive pages of the taxonomy `product_cat`. You do not need to pass the taxonomy to the function and the taxonomy is taken from the term object. You can however modify the code to work with any taxonomy
- I have written the code in such a way that if the user sets the `child_of` parameter, that value will not be used. The function will override that value

Lets look at usecases. You can use the function as follow: (*Code used from OP*)

```
$args = [
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'title_li'   => __( 'Categories' ),
    'depth'      => 3
];
custom_term_list( $args );
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @PieterGoosen, how can i get all categories by sell? i need most selling categories. please help

Comment: @MahaDev You must start a new question. This is unfortuantely not a forum and does not follow that style. ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, i am sorry i couldn't start a new question. because stakeoverflow is not allowing me to post any question due to more downvoating in the past. :(

Comment: @MahaDev Then there is unfortunately nothing I can do for you. As a user with almost 800 rep you should know that we cannot extend questions/answer as like forums do. This *has to be** asked in a new question. Sorry that I cannot help you like this